# Imgshot logout admin panel error

Tags: php

When i am in the admin area of imgshot and i want to log out from admin and click the link to log out i get the next error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: user_id in /home/****/public_html/inc/functions.php on line 371
```

The error in the line of 371 is the next one

```
where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

The whole link is the next http://justpaste.it/dt75 How i can fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

change this code:

```
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
            mysql_query("update `users`
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= ''
            where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

to this one:

```
$user_id1 = intval(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : 0, 10);
$user_id2 = intval(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) ? $_COOKIE['user_id'] : 0, 10);
if ($user_id1 || $user_id2)
    mysql_query("update `users`
        set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= ''
        where `id` in (".$user_id1.",".$user_id2.")") or die(mysql_error());
```

NOTE: it is not very secure to store user_id in cookies, as user can replace it with other value

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you check if EITHER session OR cookie value is set, but then attempt to access both.

1st, this is just a notice and not an error, so you can just ignore it if you wish.

However to fix you can try the following:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
        $user_id= isset($_SESSION['user_id'])?$_SESSION['user_id']:$_COOKIE['user_id'];
        mysql_query("update `users`
        set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= ''
        where `id`='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```